# How can I draw 50 of the same sprite in random locations in XNA?

Tags: random, xna, sprite, texture2d

I am currently working on a school project and missed a class where the instructor explained how to do this without a massive amount of code.

Here is the assignment:

*Create an XNA application shows 50 animated sprites accelerating downward.  When a sprite hits the bottom of the window, make it bounce.  Spawn each sprite in a random location such that the sprite is always completely in the window.  Limit the Y component of the random location to be between 0 and 300.  Lastly, make it so the sprites reset to their original location upon a press of the space bar.*

This is a link to an example image, rep isn't high enough for inserting images

http://hypergrade.com/grader/file_download.php?id=132

I have a single sprite drawn and animated, I just need some guidance on randomly generating locations for the same Texture2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use Random class.

```
 // Make one instance of random, the seed is the milliseconds, other way random always returns the same sequence of random numbers.
 static readonly Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Nom.Milliseconds);

 List<Sprite> Sprites = new List<Sprite>(50); 
 public void Update()
 {
      //Add new sprites with a 90% or probability 
      if (Sprites.Count<50 && rnd.Next(100) > 90)
      {
          Sprite sprite = new Sprite();

          // This X calculation makes the sprite not to get out of the screen at both sides
          sprite.Pos.X = (float) ( (0.1f + 0.8f * rnd.NextDouble()) * GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width);
          sprite.Pos.Y = (float) ( rnd.NextDouble() * 300 );

          Sprites.Add(Sprite);
      }
 }
```

Of course de Sprite class depends on you.. :)